# What is a bitter enemy?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Can anybody help me to interpret the word **bitter enemy**" ? i have googled it but still got no answer.

Comment: An enemy with great depths of feeling against you.

Comment: When you say you googled it, what exactly did you google? [bitter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bitter)  Proceeding from or exhibiting strong animosity: *a bitter struggle; bitter foes*.

Comment: @Jim, that's not the first of several definitions, finding which definition is likely to be the OP's problem. Compare "He's my bitter enemy", "He's bitter and he's my enemy".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the word "bitter". (unsurprisingly) A bitter enemy is a person who causes bitterness due to the relationship.

From Webster's 1913:

2. Causing pain or smart; piercing; painful; sharp; severe; as, a bitter cold day.
3. Causing, or fitted to cause, pain or distress to the mind; calamitous; poignant.
4. Characterized by sharpness, severity, or cruelty; harsh; stern; virulent; as, bitter reproach.
5. Mournful; sad; distressing; painful; pitiable.

http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=bitter&use1913=on&use1828=on

Answer (score 0):

Both bitter and acrid have similar meanings (so much so that the only definition I could find WITHOUT bitter is the Merriam Webster version below). Acrimonious is typically used to describe a contentious relationship. This may be the genesis of bitter when used to describe an enemy, since Latin was the language of the learned for quite a while in Europe. It's entirely possible that bitter was substituted for acrimonious as a result of mistranslation, or to make it clearer to those whose vocabulary didn't include acrimonious in English.

Acrimonious (adj.) 
:  caustic, biting, or rancorous especially in feeling, language, or manner 
— ac·ri·mo·ni·ous·ly adverb
— ac·ri·mo·ni·ous·ness noun

Additionally, bitter and sharp are often associated when speaking of flavor. Sharp can also have the same connotation as clear. Thus a bitter enemy could be a clear and obvious enemy; though this is much more tenuous and is merely speculation.